# RESTful web services framework comparison with Spring MVC REST support

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc

In one of our projects we are using the spring mvc. The spring mvc has inherent support for REST web services. I am looking forward to some insight/suggestions on how does  Springs mvc's REST support fare when compared with the other popular framework like RESTEasy, RESTlet,JAX-RS etc.

Comment: Hard to compare without any context. It's saying "compare a Ferrari with a Skoda". Well, the Skoda is cheaper so I guess it's better...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first big differentiator is that Restlet and RESTEasy both provide implementations of JAX-RS. You can write JAX-RS code that either of those frameworks could run and not have to change anything. Spring MVC is a separate API that doesn't implement JAX-RS. It does provide most of the same functionality from what I've seen. Of course, Restlet also provides its own non-JAX-RS based API which is nice too.

I found [this](http://www.infoq.com/articles/springmvc_jsx-rs) seemingly thorough comparison of Spring MVC and JAX-RS at InfoQ that might interest you. I would say, if you are already using Spring MVC and it meets your needs in the REST department, stick with it until you find a need to look for something else.